# Log convex function is actually log concave (Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning)

Tags: machine-learning, convex

In Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning Ch 6.4.6 at the bottom of page 316 the author states that $p(a_N|t_N)$ is log convex.

The author states that:

$$-\nabla \nabla \Psi(a_N)=W_N+C_N^{-1}$$

is positive definite which I agree with.

The negative of a positive definite matrix is negative definite.

So the Hessian of $\Psi(a_N)$ is negative definite.

Therefore $\Psi(a_N)$ is concave.

We have $\Psi(a_N)=log(p(a_N|t_N))$

Therefore $p(a_N|t_N)$ is log concave not log convex, since the logarithm of $p(a_N|t_N)$ is concave.

A log convex function is also convex, so if $p(a_N|t_N)$ were log convex it would also be convex which doesn't make sense since it is a probability distribution and it doesn't agree with the next statement in the book that it has a global maximum.

I couldn't find this in listed errata online.

Comment: Author states lhs is a Hessian matrix, which he denotes by A, and is second derivative of $-\psi$.  He doesn't claim it's the hessian of $+\psi$.

Comment: Thats not really relevant. If the Hessian of $-\Psi$ is positive definite then $-\Psi$ is convex which implies that $\Psi$ is concave. And if $\Psi$ is concave then $p(a_N|t_N)$ is log concave not log convex which was the whole point of the post.

Comment: the point of your post was not really clear. so you agree with all the maths and all you are saying is you have identified a typo `(|) is log con*cave*... global maximum`

Comment: The post is titled log convex function is actually log concave. I think that's pretty clear. Its not listed in any errata I could find online. I just wanted to confirm my reasoning was correct.

Comment: I believe it's a typo.